# solution to collect funds raised in ico

Tags: ico

Simple question, which are the best practices to safely store money collected by ICOs. I know multisig is an option, but after multisig suicide doesn't sound so good. There are more?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say multisig wallets are pretty ok. The problem with parity's multisig wallet was not in the contract, but in the procedures they should have followed to safely deploy it.

Comment: would you elaborate "procedures they should have followed"?

Comment: From their [post-mortem analysis](https://paritytech.io/blog/security-is-a-process-a-postmortem-on-the-parity-multi-sig-library-self-destruct.html) the fault was in the procedure to follow when deploying such critical component. They didn't have an explicit procedure, and deployment was done ad-hoc. In the rush to fix the previous bug they forgot the critical step of initializing the "library" contract.